# Adding another line to chord chart arc title from different source in d3

Tags: python, d3.js

I'm relatively new to D3 and am still trying to wrap my head around how the data sets link together.  For simplicity sake, I am using [this beautiful chord chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/) by Mike Bostock as my base design.

I've created another 35x35 matrix of fake data, a variable defined as "corr":

*In Python*

```
 corr = pandas.DataFrame(randn(35,35))
```

*Placed in the script*

```
 var corr = [[...],
            [...],
            [...],
            .
            .
            .,
            [...]];
```

*In the script, the title chunk is:*

```
 chord.append("title").text(function(d) {
     return " " + cities[d.target.index].name
      + " → " + cities[d.source.index].name
      + ": " + formatPercent(d.source.value)
      + "\n " + cities[d.source.index].name
      + " → " + cities[d.target.index].name
      + ": " + formatPercent(d.target.value);
 });
```

I think my problem is that I am trying to call from a different data set, but regardless, all of my approaches end in the chord chart or titles not appearing.

Any and all advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What are you defining 'cities' as? The example loads [this csv](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/cities.csv) into an array of objects:

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function(cities) {
```

Since you don't have any city names, the function that creates the title text crashes instead of returning creating a title.

I would recommend just using the index number in the titles:

```
 chord.append("title").text(function(d) {
     return " " + d.target.index
      + " → " + d.source.index
      + ": " + formatPercent(d.source.value)
      + "\n " + d.source.index
      + " → " + d.target.index
      + ": " + formatPercent(d.target.value);
 });
```

if you can't get that to work, you should post (http://bl.ocks.org/ or http://jsfiddle.net/) what you've done so far; it is hard to guess what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I downloaded the corresponding docs from the website, http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/cities.csv and http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/matrix.json.  Like I hinted earlier, I'm a noob and am still trying to wrap my head around how all of this works.  And, my apologies for being vague on the question.  I'll think about it some more and try to phrase the question better.  Thanks again for the reply!